# Check if Task<bool> is true or false (C#)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I had method, to check count of Landlords шт LandlordTypes

I had this code to check it

```
var type = _landlordTypeRepository.GetAll()
    .Include(x => x.Landlords)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == input.Id);

if (type.Landlords.Count > 0)
{
    throw new UserFriendlyException(L("ThisTypeIsInUse"));
}
```

But I rewrote it like this

```
var type = _landlordTypeRepository
    .GetAll()
    .AnyAsync(x=> x.Id == input.Id && x.Landlords.Any());
```

But now return type id `Task<bool>`

How I can use this in if?

Comment: You should _await_ it or get result from it

Comment: You have to `await` your query so that `Task<bool>` is unwrapped to `bool`. However, the second query is now different from the first one. The first query returned a landlord type, the second query returns `true` if the type id exists and the type contains landlords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `await`:

```
var type = await _landlordTypeRepository.GetAll().AnyAsync(x=> x.Id == input.Id && x.Landlords.Any());
```

You method must also be marked as `async`.

I recommend you get acquainted with [async - await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index).

Answer (score 3):

Use `await` to "unwrap" `Task` result

```
bool type = await _landlordTypeRepository.GetAll().AnyAsync(x=> x.Id == input.Id && x.Landlords.Any());
```

Also mark calling method as `async`

```
async Task SomeMethod() {
    //..

    bool type = await _landlordTypeRepository.GetAll().AnyAsync(x=> x.Id == input.Id && x.Landlords.Any());

    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `await` keyword or simply put `.Result` at the end of a task to get the value you are looking for.

When using `await`, your method's signature must have async and must also return a `Task` (e.g. `Task<string>` or simply `Task` for void) unless it's an event which can then be `async void`.

Using `.Result`, will block the current thread which means can freeze the UI as well!

Comment: Using `.Result` is not good for async methods.  You block the current thread and then many bad things can happen.

Comment: @Nick  I agree! But sometime there is no other choice. I might be wrong, but in constructors for example, I have to use .Result instead of await/async. Also, inside Parallel I use .Result so I intentionally block the thread otherwise if I use async, it will jump to the line after Parallel.

Comment: I would never use an async method in a constructor.  Constructors should run fast, and be independent of contexts.  Better use a factory method and make it async.

Answer (score 0):

A Task is a reference data structure used for asynchronous calls. It contains a .Result-property which will be filled with the return value once the call has completed. Since it is an asynchronous call you cannot know for sure that the call has been completed when receiving a Task the way you have done here.

There is two main ways of dealing with this:

1. If you're inside an asynchronous context (method using the async keyword), you could just use the `await`-keyword to wait for and unwrap the result.
   `var type = await _landlordRepository.GetAll().AnyAsync(...);`
2. If you're in a synchronous context, you can use Task.Wait() to await the call and then read the result value from `Task<T>.Result`.

   `var task = _landlordRepository.GetAll().AnyAsync(...).Wait();
   var type = task.Result`

As people have pointed out, using .Result is usually not advised since it is a blocking call.